# How to make change of variable in $ \int_{\mathbb R^d} |\nabla f(\lambda x)|^2 dx $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let  $f_{\lambda}(x)=f(\lambda x) \ (\lambda>0)$ and $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^d)$ (Schwartz space).

My question is: If $ \int_{\mathbb R^d} |\nabla f_{\lambda}(x)|^2 dx =  \lambda ^{r}\int_{\mathbb R^d} |\nabla f(x)|^2 dx  $ for some $r$. Then what is $r$?

Comment: What have your tried? What connection do you imagine there exists between the gradient of $f$ and the gradient of $f_{\lambda}$? Can you calculate it? What are the partial derivatives of $f_{\lambda}$? Are they related to those of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Just set $u(x) := \nabla_x f(x)$, so that $u(\lambda x) = \lambda \nabla f_\lambda (x)$. Then consider
$$\int |u(x)|^2 dx = \int |\nabla_x f(x)|^2 dx$$
Make the variable change $\lambda y = x$ so that $\lambda^d dy = dx$, thus
$$\lambda^{d} \int |u(\lambda y)|^2 dy = \int|u(x)|^2 dx $$
or
$$ \int |\nabla f_\lambda(y)|^2 dy = \lambda^{-d-2} \int|\nabla f(y)|^2 dy$$